# Does watching YouTube's videos at work violate YouTube's Terms of Service

Tags: licensing

Let us suppose that I am a programmer at a software company. Furthermore, let us suppose that I am learning a programming language that the company is using. Do I violate YouTube's Terms of Service if I am watching videos on YouTube that are explaining concepts and functionalities of the programming language following this statement in the Terms of Service:

*You may view or listen to Content for your personal, non-commercial use.*

How to correctly interpret viewing and listening to Content for commercial use?